# Quickly generate the cartesian product of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cartesian

Let's say I have a matrix `x` which contains 10 rows and 2 columns. I want to generate a new matrix `M` that contains each unique pair of rows from `x` - that is, a new matrix with 55 rows and 4 columns.

E.g.,

```
x <- matrix (nrow=10, ncol=2, 1:20)

M <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=4, nrow=55))
k <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(x))
for (j in i:nrow(x))
{
    M[k,] <- unlist(cbind (x[i,], x[j,]))
    k <- k + 1
}
```

So, `x` is:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   11
 [2,]    2   12
 [3,]    3   13
 [4,]    4   14
 [5,]    5   15
 [6,]    6   16
 [7,]    7   17
 [8,]    8   18
 [9,]    9   19
[10,]   10   20
```

And then `M` has 4 columns, the first two are one row from `x` and the next 2 are another row from `x`:

```
> head(M,10)
   X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1 11  1 11
2   1 11  2 12
3   1 11  3 13
4   1 11  4 14
5   1 11  5 15
6   1 11  6 16
7   1 11  7 17
8   1 11  8 18
9   1 11  9 19
10  1 11 10 20
```

Is there either a faster or simpler (or both) way of doing this in R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `expand.grid()` function useful for this:

```
R> GG <- expand.grid(1:10,1:10)
R> GG <- GG[GG[,1]>=GG[,2],]     # trim it to your 55 pairs
R> dim(GG)
[1] 55  2
R> head(GG)
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
5    5    1
6    6    1
R>
```

Now you have the 'n*(n+1)/2' subsets and you can simple index your original matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite grokking what you are doing so I'll just throw out something that may, or may not help.

Here's what I think of as the Cartesian product of the two columns:

```
expand.grid(x[,1],x[,2])
```

Comment: Never knew about expand.grid(). Dirk's answer brings it all together (as always...)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the "relations" package.  [Here is the vignette.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relations/vignettes/relations.pdf)  It should work like this:

```
relation_table(x %><% x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Dirk's answer:

```
idx <- expand.grid(1:nrow(x), 1:nrow(x))
idx<-idx[idx[,1] >= idx[,2],]
N <- cbind(x[idx[,2],], x[idx[,1],])

> all(M == N)
[1] TRUE
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from the other answers, here is a function implementing cartesian product of two matrices, in the case of two matrices, the full cartesian product, for only one argument, omitting one of each pair:

```
cartesian_prod <- function(M1, M2) {
if(missing(M2)) {  M2 <- M1
     ind  <- expand.grid(1:NROW(M1), 1:NROW(M2))
     ind <- ind[ind[,1] >= ind[,2],] } else {
                                          ind  <- expand.grid(1:NROW(M1), 1:NROW(M2))}
rbind(cbind(M1[ind[,1],], M2[ind[,2],]))
```

}