# Calculating a consecutive streak in data

Tags: r

I’m trying to calculate the maximum winning and losing streak in a dataset (i.e. the highest number of consecutive positive or negative values). I’ve found [a somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504832/help-me-replace-a-for-loop-with-an-apply-function) here on StackOverflow and even though that gave me some good suggestions, the angle of that question is different, and I’m not (yet) experienced enough to translate and apply that information to this problem. So I was hoping you could help me out, even an suggestion would be great.

My data set look like this:

```
> subRes
   Instrument TradeResult.Currency.
1         JPM                    -3
2         JPM                   264
3         JPM                   284
4         JPM                    69
5         JPM                   283
6         JPM                  -219
7         JPM                   -91
8         JPM                   165
9         JPM                   -35
10        JPM                  -294
11        KFT                    -8
12        KFT                   -48
13        KFT                   125
14        KFT                  -150
15        KFT                  -206
16        KFT                   107
17        KFT                   107
18        KFT                    56
19        KFT                   -26
20        KFT                   189
> split(subRes[,2],subRes[,1])
$JPM
 [1]   -3  264  284   69  283 -219  -91  165  -35 -294
$KFT
 [1]   -8  -48  125 -150 -206  107  107   56  -26  189
```

In this case, the maximum (winning) streak for JPM is four (namely the 264, 284, 69 and 283 consecutive positive results) and for KFT this value is 3 (107, 107, 56).

My **goal** is to create a function which gives the maximum winning streaks per instrument (i.e. JPM: 4, KFT: 3). To achieve that:

*R needs to compare the current result with the previous result, and if it is higher then there is a streak of at least 2 consecutive positive results. Then R needs to look at the next value, and if this is also higher: add 1 to the already found value of 2. If this value isn’t higher, R needs to move on to the next value, while remembering 2 as the intermediate maximum.*

I’ve tried `cumsum` and `cummax` in accordance with conditional summing (like `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(subRes[,2]) > 0))`), which didn’t work out. Also `rle` in accordance with `lapply` (like  `lapply(rle(subRes$TradeResult.Currency.), function(x) diff(x) > 0)`) didn’t work.

How can I make this work?

#### Edit 19 January 2011

**Calculating the size of an streak**
Besides the length of the streak, I would also like to incorporate the size of the streak in my analysis. With the answers provided below, I thought I was able to do it by myself, sadly I'm mistaken and run into the following problem(s):

With the following data frame:

```
> subRes
   Instrument TradeResult.Currency.
1         JPM                    -3
2         JPM                   264
3         JPM                   284
4         JPM                    69
5         JPM                   283
6         JPM                  -219
7         JPM                   -91
8         JPM                   165
9         JPM                   -35
10        JPM                  -294
11        KFT                    -8
12        KFT                   -48
13        KFT                   125
14        KFT                  -150
15        KFT                  -206
16        KFT                   107
17        KFT                   107
18        KFT                    56
19        KFT                   -26
20        KFT                   189
> lapply(split(subRes[,2], subRes[,1]), function(x) {
+             df.rle <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
+             df.rle <- rle(df.rle)
+ 
+             wh <- which(df.rle$lengths == max(df.rle$lengths))
+             mx <- df.rle$lengths[wh]
+             suma <- df.rle$lengths[1:wh]
+             out <- x[(sum(suma) - (suma[length(suma)] - 1)):sum(suma)]
+             return(out)
+         })
$JPM
[1] 264 284  69 283

$KFT
[1] 107 107  56
```

This result is correct, and changing the last line to `return(sum(out))` I can get the total size of the streak:

```
$JPM
[1] 900

$KFT
[1] 270
```

However, the function does not seem to count the losing streaks when changing the `ifelse` condition:

```
lapply(split(subRes[,2], subRes[,1]), function(x) {
            df.rle <- ifelse(x < 0, 1, 0)
            df.rle <- rle(df.rle)

            wh <- which(df.rle$lengths == max(df.rle$lengths))
            mx <- df.rle$lengths[wh]
            suma <- df.rle$lengths[1:wh]
            out <- x[(sum(suma) - (suma[length(suma)] - 1)):sum(suma)]
            return(out)
        })
$JPM
[1] 264 284  69 283

$KFT
[1] 107 107  56
```

I don’t see what I need to change about this function to ultimately come to the total sum of the losing streak. However I tweak/change the function, I get the same result or an error. The `ifelse` function confuses me, because it seems the obvious part of the function to change, yet doesn't result in any change. What obvious point am I missing?

Comment: Please start a new question for your edit.

Comment: @Shane: okay, perhaps that is indeed easier. I will do that after I tried some new ideas I just picked up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work:

```
FUN <- function(x, negate = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) {
    rles <- rle(x > 0)
    if(negate) {
        max(rles$lengths[!rles$values], na.rm = na.rm)
    } else {
        max(rles$lengths[rles$values], na.rm = na.rm)
    }
}
wins <- lapply(split(subRes[,2],subRes[,1]), FUN)
loses <- lapply(split(subRes[,2],subRes[,1]), FUN, negate = TRUE)
```

Giving this:

```
> wins
$JPM
[1] 4

$KFT
[1] 3
> loses
$JPM
[1] 2

$KFT
[1] 2
```

or:

```
> sapply(split(subRes[,2],subRes[,1]), FUN)
JPM KFT 
  4   3
> sapply(split(subRes[,2],subRes[,1]), FUN, negate = TRUE)
JPM KFT 
  2   2
```

You were close, but you needed to apply `rle()` to each element of your list separately, and also convert `TradeResult.Currency.` to a logical vector depending indicating above 0 or not. Our function `FUN` returns just the `lengths` component of the object returned by `rle`, and we apply `max()` to this vector of lengths to find the longest winning run.

Note that here `split` isn't necessary, and you can use the other subset-by-factor-and-apply-function functions (`tapply`, `aggregate`, etc) here:

```
> with(subRes, aggregate(`TradeResult.Currency.`, 
+                        by = list(Instrument = Instrument), FUN))
  Instrument x
1        JPM 4
2        KFT 3
> with(subRes, tapply(`TradeResult.Currency.`, Instrument, FUN))
JPM KFT 
  4   3
```

---

The reason the earlier version wasn't right, was because if you had a longer series of losses than wins (longer series of negative values), would result in the length of the losses series being selected.

The modified function adds a `'negate'` argument to swap the meaning of the test. If we want wins, we leave `TRUE` and `FALSE` in `$values` as they are. If we want losses, we swap `TRUE` and `FALSE`. We can then use this `$values` component to select only the runs that correspond to wins (`negate = TRUE`) or the runs that correspond to losses (`negate = FALSE`).

Comment: Thanks Gavin! This solves my problem, and the function is also a lot shorter than I expected it to be. Thanks :) I'm wondering though, why have you opted to use `na.rm` in the function? Googling for this statement gives a lot of code, but no real documentation. Can you tell what the use of it is in this example, because without `na.rm` in de function, I get the same output (JPM 4 KFT 3).

Comment: @Jura25 I was writing `FUN` defensively to all for an `'na.rm'` argument so that `max` will work if missing data get into the computations somewhere. In this example, you don't need it as there is no chance of missingness, but once you start using it, `max` would return `NA` if any `lengths` were `NA`. Having taken a closer look at `rle`, the `lengths` component will never contain `NA` so I was being overly defensive, and you can leave off the `na.rm = TRUE` part of the `sapply` and `lapply` calls.

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your further explanation!

Comment: Just wondering, but if I understand it correctly, I can't use this solution to calculate the length of a losing streak (i.e. values below zero)? Changing the obvious parameters gives the same result (with `rle(x <= 0)`) or an error (with `inverse.rle`). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jura25 The function was wrong in that a longer run of losses than wins would get selected. I have corrected the function to do the right thing, an in doing so I extended it to return losses or wins depending on the use of a new argument `'negate'`. There is a bit of explanation as to why the original function didn't work and why you can't swap to the condition `x < 0` to get runs of losses included at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, this works perfect, and your extra explanation is quite informative. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere nearly as slick as Gavin's solution, but here goes. My function returns the actual sequence of the longest streak.

```
inst.split <- split(inst[, 2], inst[, 1])

inst <- lapply(inst.split, function(x) {
            df.rle <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
            df.rle <- rle(df.rle)

            wh <- which(df.rle$lengths == max(df.rle$lengths))
            mx <- df.rle$lengths[wh]
            suma <- df.rle$lengths[1:wh]
            out <- x[(sum(suma) - (suma[length(suma)] - 1)):sum(suma)]
            return(out)
        })

$JPM
[1] 264 284  69 283

$KFT
[1] 107 107  56
```

If you want to know the longest streak per instrument, just do

```
lapply(inst, length)

$JPM
[1] 4

$KFT
[1] 3
```

**FOR NEGATIVE VALUES**

Notice that there's a long losing streak for KFT. I've left values for JPM (JP Morgan?) alone.

```
> inst
   Instrument TradeResult.Currency.
1         JPM                    -3
2         JPM                   264
3         JPM                   284
4         JPM                    69
5         JPM                   283
6         JPM                  -219
7         JPM                   -91
8         JPM                   165
9         JPM                   -35
10        JPM                  -294
11        KFT                    -8
12        KFT                   -48
13        KFT                  -125
14        KFT                  -150
15        KFT                  -206
16        KFT                  -107
17        KFT                  -107
18        KFT                    56
19        KFT                   -26
20        KFT                   189
```

And this is the result of running the split `data.frame` through the above function.

```
$JPM
[1] 264 284  69 283

$KFT
[1]   -8  -48 -125 -150 -206 -107 -107
```

Comment: @Roman that is a good solution, and suggests that returning something like `rle()` does would be useful here, with `lengths` and `values` components. Couple of style points: you don't need the `ifelse` bit, just apply `rle()` to `x > 0` directly (the logical gets interpreted as `0`,`1`. You can also use `which.max` in place of your `which`: `which.max(df.rle$lengths)`.

Comment: Thanks Roman, that looks quite elaborate (and works perfect!). Besides that, with an minor change in your function I was able to calculate the total value of an streak (which would have been my next step in the analysis). Thanks! :)

Comment: @Gavin, I already wrote everything when I saw your answer. I left it in to diversify and show Jura25 an extra function he may not be familiar with. I didn't know about x > 0, but I like it.

Comment: @Roman: I've used your script to calculate the total size of an winning streak, however, I can't seem to get it to work to do the same for losses. I've tried using `negate` and the inverse (`!`) in the function, but I either end up with the same result or wrong values coupled with a warning message. Changing the `ifelse` seems the most obvious way to do it, however strangely enough this still gives the same results. Can a version of your function be changed to display the same results for losses?

Comment: I've changed a few values for FKT to negative so that I get a long losing streak, and function works "out of the box". Are you sure you're not using some weird (reduntant) object?

Comment: Thanks Roman for your further clarification. I was able to replicate your example, but now I'm even more confused. Am I correct in stating that the `ifelse` statement in this function serves no purpose? This because if the longest streak of KFT is negative, it returns that instead of the positive streak it does for JPM. I'm afraid that means the function cannot be used to calculate the winning or losing streak (and the total value thereof) because it returns the longest streak, regardless of + or - values? I'm sorry to bother you (again:P) with this, but I hope you can shed some light on this.

Comment: The 'ifelse' is there to shape the data in such a manner that is recognized by 'rle'. It should not interfere with the end result (see my example result under negative values)... Unless I'm missing something rather obvious you're trying to tell me?

Comment: @Roman: Sorry for my late response, I didn't notice this comment until today. I have the idea where both saying the same thing, though I as a beginner I'm puzzling to find the right words/terms to illustrate what I mean. I've updated my original question with an example of what I mean, I hope that makes it somewhat clearer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a loop to calculate the length of the winning and losing streaks for any length of data (in this example, x is a vector of numbers that you are interested in). The problem with this issue is that the maximum winning or losing streak may not coincide with the longest length of the winning streak. Therefore, there needs to be a separate / independent calculation:

```
rout <- rle (x>=0) # In this calculation, 0 is considered a "win"

losel <- max(rout$lengths[!rout$values]) # Length of max losing streak
winl <- max(rout$lengths[rout$values]) # Length of max winning streak

xpostemp <- cumsum(rout$lengths)
xpos <- c(0,xpostemp)
looplength <- length(xpos)-1
tot <- rep (0,looplength)

for(j in 1:looplength){
    start <- xpos[j]+1
    end <- xpos[j+1]
    tot[j] <- sum(x[start:end])                
}
winmax <- max(tot) # Sum of largest winning steak
losemax <- min(tot) # Sum of largest losing streak
```

Apologies as it looks cumbersome, I'm not a full time programmer, but I think you will find that this works.